# How to import module from package read in from string?

Tags: python, string, python-import, python-importlib, import-libraries

Say I have a string: `'src.utils.random_num'`

How can I import `random_num` and actually execute it.  What I have thus far:

```
from importlib import import_module


def parse_module(module_path):
    package = '.'.join(module_path.split('.')[:-1])
    module = module_path.split('.')[-1]
    return package, module

req_import = parse_module('src.utils.random_num')
# import the package, works fine
module = import_module(req_import[0])

# how can I access and execute `random_num` via `req_import[1]`?
module.random_num()
```

How can I evaluate that `random_num` is a function and execute it dynamically?

Comment: python version?

Comment: @DevonHorizon 3.7

Comment: Use the spec_from_file_location from importlib.util. You create the spec and then module_from_spec(spec) and load it.

Comment: @DevonHorizon awesome, I’ll take a look! Really appreciate it

Comment: One thing to note, I did make the assumption that you needed to load a module from a file location. with a namespace you could use other better options.

Comment: @DevonHorizon AFK now but if you’d post some examples in the answers that would be amazing.. really appreciate you helping me out. Thank you!

Comment: is this answering your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)